# Why is the organization of the displays changed when I change the primary monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Demo:

[image]

Why is the organization of the displays changed when I change the primary monitor?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: The picture does not really replace 1000 words :-)  If you could crop it up to fit the web space and show only that section, then do a before and after with the primary highlighted , I think it would show everything. Crop, point to primary, before change and after change please.

Comment: @Psycogeek I posted the answer I found. Let me know if unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving the windows around a bit more, at some point they got "vertically centered", and it fixed the issue:

[image]

Microsoft Windows seem to have some minor UI issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, that doesn't look like any intended feature of Windows (i.e. it's a glitch/bug). It looks like the horizontal arrangement of your displays is still maintained, so unless the vertical arrangement change on the graphic is actually representative of the ability to extend the screen off the top of the primary monitor (which would be impressive and hilarious!), this shouldn't be too much of an issue.

As for why it occurs in the first place, the only thing I can think of that might be a contributing factor is that in the animation, you select "Make this my main display", yet the "Multiple Displays" dropdown below still shows "Extend desktop **to** this display". That's not normal - if one display is the main display, you should be extending the desktop **from** that display, not to it. Try changing that option away to something different.